# I can't run my app on my android phone "sh: applet not found"

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

when I started to run my app via eclipse on my phone but in console it's show "ActivityManager: sh: applet not found" anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still active but since I found it while researching the same problem, maybe an answer can help others.

In my case, the "sh: applet not found" message was due to a problem with the Busybox installation on my Android device. Busybox installs symlinks that direct to the main sh applet, but if they are not set correctly, certain applications will not be able to execute sh.

The problem can be resolved by copying the correct busybox bin to a second location. Try copying `/sbin/busybox.bin` to `/system/xbin/busybox`, which worked on my device.

Sources for further reading (thanks to ketut.kumajaya on XDA for the fix):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16635801&postcount=602

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16909450&postcount=661

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project and build it again. That may help.